# Received memory warning then 'Lost connection to iPhone'.

Tags: ios, memory, camera, usage-statistics

I use the below code snippet to open the camera, click a photo and use the photo (when the two options, *Retake* and *Use Photo*, appear).

```
- (IBAction)openCamera
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [imageSpinner stopAnimating];
        [imageSpinner removeFromSuperview];
        [cameralabel setText:@""];
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
            [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            imagePicker.delegate = self;
            imagePicker.sourceType =
            UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
            [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
            imagePicker=nil;
        }
    }
}

-(void)setImageSpinner
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        imageSpinner = nil;
        imageSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        imageSpinner.center = self.view.center;
        [imageSpinner startAnimating];
        [self.view addSubview:imageSpinner];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:imageSpinner];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self openCamera];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    NSString *savedImagePath;
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image 1.jpeg"];
        paths=nil;
        documentsDirectory=nil;
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NULL];
        [cameralabel setText:@"Please wait"];
        [self setImageSpinner];
    }
    @autoreleasepool {
        ManifestDocumentViewController *manifestVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"manifestImage"];
        manifestVC.getTempFilePath = savedImagePath;
       if ([screenName isEqualToString:@"Retake"])
        {
            manifestVC.screenName = @"Retake";
            manifestVC.retakeFileID = retakeFileID;
            manifestVC.retakeFilePath = retakeFilePath;
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:savedImagePath];
            [data writeToFile:retakeFilePath atomically:YES];
            data=nil;
        }
        else
        {
            manifestVC.screenName = @"Camera";
            UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
           NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];
            [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
            image=nil;
            imageData=nil;
        }
        savedImagePath=nil;
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:manifestVC animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    picker.delegate=nil;
    picker=nil;
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
}
```

During a debugging session on iPhone 4s, the memory spikes up as shown by the memory usage under the Debug navigator.  Attached along side is a screenshot of the Memory Usage comparison. The raise in 'Other Processes' is a matter of concern.

[image: Memory Usage, App Debugging]

*Received memory warning* also appears among the displayed logs. After running the code a number of times the app crashes (The message 'Lost connection to iPhone'). This corresponds to a spike in the memory and the 'Free' memory being consumed completely.

Can the above code be optimised as far as possible to ensure that the memory usage gets reduced as much as possible.

Comment: How did you fix this?